# about custom rails 3 scaffold template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in the default index.html.erb template there didn't display id ,created_at,updated_at columns

so now i want to display them by change the template
but i didn't find the meta variant,here is the part of the original index.html.erb template file code,it use a `attributes` to display all user defined column,but didn't show default columns,dose someone know how to add this 3 columns

```
<% for attribute in attributes -%>
   <div class="field">
    <%%= f.label :<%= attribute.name %> %><br />
    <%%= f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.name%> %>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're looking for, this should be it.
I don't watch in the database but just in the model for the presence of the fields you want to show, I hope is enough...
Here is the line to put before the loop, this is the one for the id.

```
<%%= 'Id: ' + @<%= singular_table_name %>.id.to_s unless @<%= singular_table_name %>.methods.index(:id).nil? %>
```

moreover I could say that there is for sure a better way to check the presence of the field instead of using the index function, and probably a better way overall, but this works.

Answer (score -1):

You have doubly wrapped in asp style tags:

```
Id: <%= object.id %>
Created at: <%= object.created_at %>
Updated at: <%= object.updated_at %>
```

That code should show the 3 columns as you desired, or they don't exist, see if they're in the database table.

Comment: use doubly wrapped because i didn't want to it executed,it's a scaffold template(build template for template)